# Does "Image Privacy" (EXIF remover) app still exist?

Tags: applications

Does the "Image Privacy" app exist in some form?  It was a very handy method of removing EXIF data from an image expressly for sharing the metadata-free image.  You select "Share" -> "Strip metadata" (the Image Privacy intent) and then the target app.

A screenshot:

[image: Image Privacy screenshot]

[image source](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/image-privacy-remove-metadata-from-photos/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Photo Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iudesk.android.photo.editor) for EXIF removal.

See screenshot below

> [image: Screenshot]